# How to fix this errors when instaling @popperjs/core

Tags: angular, bootstrap-5, popperjs

i installed ng-bootstrap with this commande in my Angular project : `npm i @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap --legacy-peer-deps`

then i installed popperjs with this commande : `npm install @popperjs/core --save`

when i run the angular server , i'm getting those errors :

```
./node_modules/@popperjs/core/lib/index.js:4:0-102 - Error: export 'detectOverflow' (reexported as 'detectOverflow') was not found in './createPopper.js' (possible exports: createPopper, popperGenerator)

./node_modules/@popperjs/core/lib/popper-lite.js:11:0-75 - Error: export 'detectOverflow' (reexported as 'detectOverflow') was not found in './createPopper.js' (possible exports: createPopper, popperGenerator)

./node_modules/@popperjs/core/lib/popper.js:16:0-75 - Error: export 'detectOverflow' (reexported as 'detectOverflow') was not found 
in './createPopper.js' (possible exports: createPopper, popperGenerator)
```

I don't know how to fix this probleme

Answer (score 0):

In `./.angular.json` at the row `scripts` :

`"../node_modules/popper.js/dist/esm/popper.js"`

> or:

`"../node_modules/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.js"`

Comment: i don't have  this : "../node_modules/popper.js/dist/esm/popper.js"   in my /.angular.json

Comment: did u try to add it? do u have /node_modules/popper.js/dist/ folder?